# При парсинге получаю другю страницу

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

```
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

url = 'https://www.binance.com/ru/nft/goods/blindBox/detail?productId=210121&isOpen=false&isProduct=1' # url страницы
r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': UserAgent().chrome})
with open('test.html', 'w') as output_file:
  output_file.write(r.text)
```

Пытаюсь спарсть страницу, но на та страница которую я спрасил отличается от той которая в браузере

Comment: У вас подгружается js, который создает уже страницу или проверяет бот ли зашел. Здесь нужно что-то типа Selenium

Comment: У большинства криптобирж есть API: получаешь токен + секретный ключ и можно проще парсить.
самый передовой это ccxt, он поддерживает много криптобирж
https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt